# routeprovider using resolve to pass value to controller

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm looking for a way to pass a value to my controller from my appRoutes. With the idea for it to call a function and do some magic. heres some code so you get an idea:

**appRoutes.js**

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/students/some/path/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/studentRecord.html',
    controller:  'StudentsController',
    resolve:     { myVar: 'test' }
  });
```

**studentsCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('StudentsCtrl', [])
  .controller('StudentsController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams,
                                             $location, myVar, Students) {
     /* ... */
   });
```

Ideally, I'd like to call a given function within this controller - but parsing a value would be just as good. The idea is that the controller handles all pages to do with 'students' and will make some http calls so my node server will do some calls to mongodb. Ive tried a few variations on the internet and with no luck. I got an error:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

**EDIT:** I've half resolved this now by using this; http://plnkr.co/edit/mSb58e8cGDNYU27xSizk?p=preview

ideally i'd like to separate the app.js into controllers and services - currently working on this, any edit of the plnkr would be great.

Question still stands of is it possible to hit a function within the controller first, rather than resolving one through a service?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "hit a function within the controller". Is that what you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/j3s49eNTGJgV0GLZfLZT?p=preview?

Comment: inside the controller you 'hit' i want there to be a function, that it runs.

sidenote; ive tried splitting the app.js file into controllers but keep getting 'Uncaught object' :/

Comment: So, you want to pass a function to the controller instead of passing a string, is that right? Then just return a function instead of returning 'Object passed'.

Comment: Ideally I would like my route to call my studentcontroller multiple times but handled different every time depending on the url (perfrm different tasks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each `resolve` property, you can have a function that lets Angular inject services for you to use:

```
resolve: {
    myVar1: function(testService) { return testService.fetchList1(); },
    myVar2: function(anotherService, $http) {
        // call service functions to mongo-db or what have you
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, your controller, just inject the properties:

```
// myVar1 and myVar2 are now here
app.controller('StudentsController', function($scope, myVar1, myVar2) {
    /* ... */
});
```

If the returned value from the function inside `resolve` is a `promise`, then it will be resolved before controller code is called (hence, the name `resolve`). This is actually the recommended approach as it makes service code (such as `testService`) reusable across many controllers.

Comment: Issue here is I will have loads of single services performing a single task. Id rather have one service that does multiple tasks, is this possible?

Comment: @OwainFormby A service can have many `functions` inside and it's up to you to create them accordingly. For example, `testService.fetchStudents(idList)`, `testService.fetchClasses(nameList)` and the list goes on. There's nothing stopping you from adding any number of functions you want.

Comment: Any chance of a plnkr demostrating the splitting of the routes, controller and service

Comment: @OwainFormby Unfortunately, I can't share you my code at work. Though after searching around, I think this video should help. It basically guides you step-by-step on how to refactor code out from `controller` into `service` (the video uses `factory` but it's working the same way). In his example, he has two functions `login` and `logout`. So as you can see, `service` can have more than one `function` inside. You can call `service` function with parameter(s) so it's very flexible/reusable: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ovXYLGFtc4

Comment: @OwainFormby Or, if instead of a video, you like some source code to play with, you can read this. The blog owner also has a link to his own code on Github, and the code has it all (controller, service, route): http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved

Comment: Will have a good look when I get home and let you know, been a great help so far thank you

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function that returns the value

```
.state('tab2', {
                url: '/tab2',
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab2.html',
                controller: 'Tab2Controller as tab2Ctrl',
                //promise
                resolve: {
                    lastName: function  () { return 'makarov'}
                }
            });
```

Then in the controller

```
function Tab2Controller(lastName) {
    console.log("Tab2", lastName);
}
```